# symmetric group, eigeproblem

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I am working in a problem which turn out that in one of its limits I have to solve the eigenvalue problem for a random permutation matrix.

I would like to know therefore more about the symmetric group, and more specifically about spectral properties of permutation matrices. Where can I study the symmetric group and try to understand it from a pedagogical point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you identifying the symmetric group $S_n$ with its regular representation (i.e. its permutation representation), by any chance? In other words, are you identifying e.g. the cycle $(123)\in S_3$ with the matrix
$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right) $, the matrix that implements a $(123)$ permutation of the three basis vectors of $\mathbb C^3$?

If so, there is an easy way to find the eigenvalues. In the example above for $(123)$ the eigenvalues are $1, \zeta_3, \zeta_3^2$, where $\zeta_3 = \exp(2\pi i /3)$.

The eigenvectors are $(1,1,1), (1,\zeta_3^2, \zeta_3), (1, \zeta_3, \zeta_3^2)$, which you can verify by substitution.

To give you another example, if you're given $(123)(45678) \in S_8$, then the eigenvalues are $1, \zeta_3, \zeta_3^2$ and $1, \zeta_5, \zeta_5^2, \zeta_5^3, \zeta_5^4$, i.e. you read them off from the individual cycles. Hopefully you can see why this is true and hopefully you can guess what the corresponding eigenvectors are by extrapolating the previous example.

Comment: Exactly this is the problem. Do you know if exits an algorithm such that if I have the matrix, I can know the cycle decomposition of the permutation?

Comment: Plus, do you have a reference where I can check the proof of this theorem?

Comment: Don't write down the matrix. Write down the cycle structure of the permutation.

Comment: Let me write down a third example: $(12)(345)(6789)$. The eigenvalues are $1,-1$, $1,\zeta_3, \zeta_3^2$, $1, \zeta_5, \zeta_5^2, \zeta_5^3, \zeta_5^4$. Do you see the common pattern in the three examples?

Comment: I can't think of a good reference, but I strongly suggest you verify that $(1,1,1), (1,\zeta_2^2, \zeta_3), (1,\zeta_3, \zeta_3^2)$ are the correct eigenvectors in the for $(123)$ and think about why this works and how this generalises. It's much more simple that you might have thought, but you just need to play around with it.

Comment: I do found a reference. Check the book __Circulant matrices__ by Davies, p29, Wiley, New York, 1979. At the end, everything reduces to calculate the eigenproblem of a circulant matrix, and we know how to calculate the eigenvalues analitycally.